# phpmyadmin throwing this same error: The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php-7.4

I hope that my answer will not get closed again,I'm still not getting the right answer. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and php7.4, i've already tried to uncomment `extension=mysqli` in php.ini and restarted the apache2 and mysql services... i've searched a lot on the internet to fix this annoying problem but nothing is working for me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you apt get install php7.4-mysql

Comment: We can't really answer your question in any detail because you also didn't provide any real detail. See [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your problem. That can be tricky, with config problems, we understand. But aside from guessing or putting our own personal experiences there's not much we can do. And there's already a thread for general issues with the mysqli extension, which is shown in the blue box above. There's nothing in your details to suggest that your situation is in fact really any different. If you can provide some hard evidence, then we talk. But "Nothing worked" isn't evidence.